# How to include parameters inside a getter in JSF?

Tags: jsf, el, myfaces

I was wondering if it was possible to pass parameters without using action/actionListener.

Here is an example:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.getItem(5)}"/>
```

```
public String getItem(int index) {
     return itemList[index];
}
```

If the following does not work, is there another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: If `itemList` not empty and has value in `index`, you can get it in you facelet.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  How can you get the same result with a facelet?  Sorry I am new to JSF.  Lastly, would the sample code I gave work?

Comment: Just try it and let us know?

Comment: Yes, there is no problems in your code, try to deploy your application to the server and look at the result.

Comment: I've tried it before but I get the following error, "cannot be resolved as a member of" etc.  If I remove the parameter like so: <h:outputText value="#{myBean.getItem}">, it works fine.

Comment: Is your `getItem` method in your `myBean` or in other controller?

Comment: Everything is contained inside the same bean.

Comment: why not just write `<h:outputText value="#{myBean.itemList[5]}"/>`, and implement a getter method for `itemList`?

Comment: Seems like you are using earlier version of EL (< 2.2) and they don't support direct method calls from view. Can you tell us more about your environment , server , jars in your projects etc.

Comment: tt_emrah, the example I used just happen to be an array, but it could have been a list or some other data structure.  I just wanted to find an example where I needed to pass parameters.

Comment: Avinash Singh, I'm using jdk7, myfaces-2.2.3, tomcat7... I don't know what else I should mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using myfaces on Tomcat 7 which already ships with EL 2.2 ,

Make sure you have added below in web.xml and web.xml has `version="3.0"`,

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EXPRESSION_FACTORY</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Also make sure there are no el-api or el-imp jars in your WEB-INF/lib